# Add the extra details when editing profle in area51 to other sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

I noticed when editing my area51 profile that there were some extra explanation details under some fields.

[image]

It would be nice if we could have this on other SE sites too.

Comment: +1 I believe the email field was a subject of a discussion on Meta a little while ago.